# How to transfer from JFK to Newark using public transportation?

Tags: transit, public-transport, airport-transfer, ewr, jfk

In a couple days, I will be flying into JFK, then I'll have to catch a connecting domestic flight at Newark. The duration between scheduled landing at JFK and departure at Newark is 4 hours and 50 minutes.

The public transportation option I could figure out is :

- AirTrain to Jamaica Center
- E subway line to Penn Station
- NJ Transit train to Newark Airport station

Another possible option is :

- AirTrain to Jamaica Center
- LIRR to Penn Station
- NJ Transit train to Newark Airport station

As I did not find clear information about doing this transfer, which of both is the most practical and cost-effective? Is LIRR that much faster than the subway?

Also, can I buy a single ticket for the whole route or do I need to buy another ticket at Penn Station for the remainder of the trip?

And lastly, given the available transfer time, can we plan hanging out in NYC maybe for 30 min - 1 hour or should we better head straight to Newark?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find complete information on the LIRR and subway at http://mta.info.

Generally, the LIRR is faster, more comfortable, and more expensive.

The LIRR takes 20 minutes from Jamaica to Penn Station.  It is a commuter train with regular coach cars; there is a seat for every passenger and overhead racks for small bags.  The regular adult fare is $9.50 during peak times (M-F from about 6-10 AM in this direction), $7.00 at other times on weekdays; It's $4.00 on Saturday and Sunday.  The trains run at fixed times and you can find a timetable [here](http://web.mta.info/lirr/Timetable/Branch/CityTerminalBranch.pdf).

The E train takes about 40-45 minutes to Penn Station.  (Note that Airtrain access is via the Sutphin Blvd stop, not Jamaica Center.)  Cars have limited seating and no luggage racks; there is a fair chance that you will have to stand with your luggage for the whole trip.   The regular adult fare is $2.50 at any time of day.  The trains run frequently but don't have a fixed schedule.

You will need to buy 2-3 separate tickets for the different legs of this journey:

- To ride Airtrain from JFK to the LIRR or E train, the fare is $5, paid with a [Metrocard](http://web.mta.info/metrocard/).  You can get a Metrocard at a vending machine; there should be some on the Airtrain platforms or inside the airport.  Cash and credit cards are accepted.  There is a $1.00 surcharge for the Metrocard itself, or if you already have one, you can just add money to it.  More information about Airtrain can be found [here](http://web.mta.info/mta/airtrain.htm) and [here](http://www.panynj.gov/airports/jfk-airtrain.html).
- If you take the subway, the fare is also paid with a Metrocard.
- If you take the LIRR, you should buy a ticket from a vending machine on the LIRR platform before boarding, which will accept cash or credit cards.  If you don't, you can also buy a ticket from the conductor on the train, but there is a surcharge of about $6 and only cash is accepted.
- When you get to Penn Station, you'll need to buy another ticket for [NJ Transit](http://www.njtransit.com), preferably from a vending machine (cash or credit).  (There is also a staffed ticket window, and you can also buy from the conductor on the train, but again there is a surcharge.)  The regular adult fare to Newark Airport is $12.50.  You use the same ticket to ride the EWR Airtrain monorail from the Newark Airport station to the airport terminal itself, so do not lose it.

Note that the subway, LIRR and NJ Transit platforms are all in different parts of Penn Station, so allow yourself some extra time to navigate your connection there.

You might be able to squeeze in an hour or so to look around NYC.  I would suggest that when you get to Penn Station, you check the schedule of departing trains (you want either the Northeast Corridor or North Jersey Coast lines), choose a train that will get you to EWR with as much time as you want (I'd allow 30-40 minutes from Penn Station to EWR's terminal), and then see how much time you have in between.

Comment: @DavLink One thing to note is that nowhere in New York is there a place to leave your luggage.  If you are going to look around NYC for a bit, you'll have to drag your luggage with you everywhere.  There's no place in Penn Station or anywhere in the city itself.  This is, allegedly, as a security precaution.

Comment: @Aleks There are private companies that offer it though from a quick [google search](http://www.nyc.com/visitor_guide/luggage_storage_in_new_york_city.75878/editorial_review.aspx) - never had to use any of them though so can't vouch for them.

Comment: @AleksG, Amtrak has a bag-check service that will store your bags in Penn Station. They change a fee of something between $5 - $8 per bag. I'm pretty sure you don't need an Amtrak ticket for this but I could be wrong. Also, they are not open at night so you'd have verify their hours if you need the service in the late evening/night time.

Answer (score 10):

There's also an option of a direct shuttle connection.  [ETS Air Shuttle](http://www.etsairportshuttle.com/) has scheduled minibuses between JFK and EWR. The cost is $32 each way and, depending on the traffic, it takes 60-90 minutes.  It may seem expensive, but it's a direct terminal to terminal connection without any additional transfers or requirements to drag your luggage around.

Comment: this is the only realistic option, if you're stuck doing this