# From JFK to Newark. Time & transportation alternatives

Tags: transit, public-transport, airport-transfer, jfk, ewr

I am traveling from Indianapolis to JFK and then I need to go to Newark to catch another plane.

I have booked the 2 flights independently. If everything goes according to schedule, I will be at JFK at 4pm 12th DEC. My flight from Newark departs at 11:55pm, so I guess I should be there at 10 -10:30 pm or earlier.

Is this enough time? It may sound dummy but I have no idea from NY city and I am afraid I will stuck in a traffic jam (are the roads busy during these hours?).

So this arises a second question. How can I go from JFK to Newark?

Which is the fastest, cheapest and (more importantly) safest route to follow?

Given the circumstances, what would you suggest?

[How to transfer from JFK to Newark using public transportation?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/42797/how-to-transfer-from-jfk-to-newark-using-public-transportation)

[Options for JFK to EWR transfer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/58282/options-for-jfk-to-ewr-transfer)

I have read these two, the first for public transportation, but the second one kind made me have second thoughts about the gap I have between the flights.

Hope someone can help me...

Comment: It should be enough time.  Roads definitely are busy at that time, but not so busy that you will be unlikely to make your flight.  The fastest and cheapest routes will not be the same; you should probably avoid cheap to reduce the chance of missing your flight.  The second question you link to is about an international arrival, which is usually more time consuming than a domestic arrival because of immigration formalities and possibly also because of customs formalities.

Comment: Sure.  Another factor in your decision will be how much luggage you are carrying with you.

Comment: one big suitcase and a carry on item. I think I can handle this If I use public transportation. Or the public transportation are too unfriendly with travelers?

Comment: Not unfriendly, just crowded.  Tourists traveling to and from JFK are a common sight on the subway lines that connect to the air train as well as on the LIRR.  I would recommend the LIRR if you're determined to take the train.

Comment: ...how did it go? I am doing the exact same thing and was wondering how your experience was. thx. David

Comment: Hi David, it went very well. I was in Newark (approximately) in 2 hours (or less). The train from penn state to Newark was packed. My only advice is not afraid to ask someone for help in case you want to be sure that you are taking the correct train etc.

Comment: @sakas are you able to write an answer for future users?

Answer (score 1):

You should be alright, your connection time is generous. But if your incoming flight has serious delays you might run into some trouble. In that case you may need to go for the fast option rather than the cheap one, or be late for your second flight and miss it.

The trains, both subway and LIRR will be busy and can get crowded at peak times, but the locals are used to tourists and two pieces of luggage are acceptable even when busy. The LIRR seems to be the better choice with luggage.

While the people in New York City have the reputation of being hurried and unfriendly, they are mostly friendly when you ask for help which train to take and directions to get where you need to go.