# Transportation options from EWR to JFK airport

Tags: airport-transfer, new-york-city, jfk, ewr

I have to catch an international flight from JFK on a Monday night. Looking for transportation options from EWR to JFK. Is Uber the cheapest option?

Comment: Probably not. Uber seems like an expensive and slow option to me.

Comment: How much time do you have between your flights?

Comment: See https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/58282/options-for-jfk-to-ewr-transfer and https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/42797/how-to-transfer-from-jfk-to-newark-using-public-transportation and reverse the steps.

Comment: No, Uber is definitely not the cheapest.  What is you primary factor?  Time, convenience, cost?